# What's the KISS-way of turning format '1000 days' into format 2 years, 9 months, 0 days' within bash & shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

What's the "Keep It Simple" way of turning a format such as '1000 days' into format '2 years, 9 months, 0 days' within shell scripting?

I've thought of applying modulor or floor rounding. I've had a look into similar questions, but they were not heading in direction 'short and simple', had additional requirements, making everything more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

With `dateutils`:

```
$ today=$(dseq -f %F now)
$ ddiff -f '%y years, %m months and %d days' "$today" "$(dadd "$today" 1000)"
2 years, 8 months and 26 days
```

Given that months have variable number of days, you'll find the result depends on the starting day (here today).

On some systems, the names of the `dateutils` utilities are prefixed with `dateutils.` (`dateutils.dseq`, `dateutils.dadd`, `dateutils.ddiff`) to disambiguate from similarly named commands from other packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you trivialise the operations, a straightforward application of integer arithmetic will get you an approximate answer:

```
d=1000           # days interval

yd=365           # days per year
md=$((yd/12))    # days per month

y=$((d/yd))      # years
d=$((d-y*yd))    # remaining days

m=$((d/md))      # months
d=$((d-m*md))    # remaining days

echo y=$y, m=$m, d=$d
```

Output

```
y=2, m=9, d=0
```

---

For the purposes of testing we can squeeze this into a(n unreadable) function, and then explore some of its limitations:

```
ymd() ( d=$1; echo -n "$d ==> "; yd=365; y=$((d/yd)); d=$((d-y*yd)); md=$((yd/12)); m=$((d/md)); d=$((d-m*md)); echo "y=$y, m=$m, d=$d"; )
```

Then we get the answer you want:

```
ymd 1000
1000 ==> y=2, m=9, d=0
```

And

```
ymd $((2*365))
730 ==> y=2, m=0, d=0
```

But because there are not 12 months of 30 days in a year,

```
ymd $((2*365 -1))
729 ==> y=1, m=12, d=4
```